# how to unified date format in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join two tables called **c** and **d** respectively.

So I wrote the followings:

```
select * from c
join d
on c.date=d.date;
```

But since their date formats are different, it doesn't work. The date format in C is 1994-01. Another is 1/1/94.

I tried the following ways to unify the two tables' date format:

1. `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1 January 1994', %M %Y') AS Date from d;`
2. `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m.%Y') from d;`

what should I do?

Comment: That looks as easy as to never ever store `Date` types as `Strings`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from c
join d
on c.date = DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(d.date,'%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m');
```

There seems to be an issue with the join on DATE
If we convert the c.date to 01-01-1994, then the join with d will only be on the same dates ie 01-01-1994
Depending on the use case, better approach would be to convert d.date to yyyy-mm format, you will have a join on the basis of month.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have made a change to that:

select * from c
join d
on c.date = DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(d.date,'%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m');

then it works now. Thank you.